# Nginx error_page seemingly returns 503 instead of serving capacity page when 503 encountered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I wanted to make it so that if nginx encountered a 503 or a 504, it redirected to a static url /capacity.  When I deployed to my staging server, instead, it seemingly just returns that the site is over capacity, even though it isn't.  The odd thing is, it didn't do this with the prior config:

Old config:

```
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
   location = /50x.html {
}
```

New config:

```
# redirect server error pages to the static route /500
#
error_page 500 502 /500;
    location = /500 {
}

# redirect over capacity error pages to the static route /capacity
#
error_page 503 504 /capacity;
    location = /capacity {
}
```

Whenever I visit the site now, I get a Chrome error page:

staging is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 503

Is this not the correct way of handling this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dynamic site then location /dynamic will not work. What location is doing is its returning content of /dynamic path without hitting your application. You should use redirect to so the request wll redirect and hit application.

Redirect sample code

return 301 http://www.example.com